# How can I get GDB to stop asking me for symbols?

Tags: assembly, gdb, msp430

I am debugging a remote stub (embedded, assembly). I can connect just fine:

```
$ msp430-gdb -nx -ex 'target remote XXX'
```

…

```
Remote debugging using XXX
0x00004400 in ?? ()
(gdb)
```

Now when I try and set a breakpoint, GDB whines about not having symbols:

```
(gdb) b 0x4404
No symbol table is loaded.  Use the "file" command.
Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or [n]) n
(gdb)
```

How can I tell it to not ask me about "future library loads" or not having a symbol table? The remote will never have either of these things. Thanks!

Edit: I am an idiot. The syntax to break on address is 'b *addr'. GDB was interpreting 0x4404 as a line number or symbol or something stupid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FWIW the answer to your original question is to use "set breakpoint pending"; the default is "auto", but you can either use "on" or "off" to automatically make or reject pending breakpoints.